# CSS cursor : pointer in a row ( IE )

Tags: css, internet-explorer

CSS `cursor : pointer` in a row doesn't work on IE. Any workarounds ?

Comment: assign cursor: pointer to table cells (td)

Comment: Where? problem with "a" tag? or td? please http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a table row ? and which version of IE are you using?

http://jsfiddle.net/kKdSh/ works for me on IE9.

Answer (score 1):

in your css, insert a line, set "display:inline-block;"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your CSS:

```
#modelTable td, #modelTable th
{
    width:90px;
    cursor: hand; 
}
```

For information, refer to [IE-CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I had it tested and it worked for me.